# webpack does not support async/await keyword

Tags: webpack, async-await, ecmascript-2017

Usually, we use webpack + babel to transform es6/7 code with this config.

```
    test: /\.js[x]?$/,
    loader: 'babel-loader',
    query: {
      presets: ['es2017', 'react'],
    },
```

It works perfectly. And the code can be run on Chrome/Firefox/Edge/Safari. (Let's forget IE.)

But, Chrome 55 is released with native support for async/await. So I remove 'es2017' from 'presets'.

```
    presets: ['react'],
```

Then, webpack complains: "**SyntaxError: Unexpected token**".

So, my question is: How can we take the advantage of native async/await feature in jsx?

Comment: Here's my take on this- Even if chrome supports async/await functions, it doesn't mean webpack understands what you're doing at the time of bundling. It still needs to go through babel.

Comment: FYI, "ES7" is a synonym for ES2016, not ES2017.

Comment: We'd like to try native async/await with webpack/react. Is there any workaround to let webpack bundle the code with async/await keyword? Or is there any other bundling tool which can do it?

Comment: By the way, it is not perfect to transform async/await to generator. The generated code would change "this" since it wraps the whole code into a function.

Comment: Done. Use webpack 2 + AsyncAwaitPlugin.